# How to set a value on computed property

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, properties

I want to set a value to a key in a computed property of type dictionary. I want to do something like this:

```
class Foo {
    var dict: [String: String] {
        dict["a"] = "b"
    }
}
```

However that doesn't compile.

> Cannot assign through subscript: 'dict' is a get-only property

I can do something like this but it's a bit verbose:

```
class Foo {
    var values: [String: String] {
        var tempValues = [String: String]()
        tempValues["a"] = "b"
        return tempValues
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this? For context, what I want to achieve is having `dict` by default to be an empty `[String: String]()` in a base class and when I override the property in a subclass I want to assign values to said dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and when I override the property in a subclass I want to assign values to said dictionary.

Ehh... Just do it:

```
class A {
    var dict: [String: String] {
        return [:]
    }
}

class B: A {
    override var dict: [String : String] {
        return ["Hello":"Hi"]
    }
}
```

Did you forget the `override` keyword?

Comment: That makes sense but I'm getting hung up on `return ["Hello":"Hi"]`. How would you amend the dictionary if say you had a `class C`?

Comment: @Aaron Do exactly the same as you did in `B`, just change the return value.

Comment: Right, but to what exactly? If there's 20 k-v pairs before I override, it won't let me assign `food["bar"] = "baz"`.

Comment: @Aaron It's a computed property, so just return the values you want to have in the dictionary! Instead of doing `food["bar"] = "baz"`, do `return ["bar": "baz"]`

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
var dict: [String: String] {
    dict["a"] = "b"
}
```

is the short form for

```
var dict: [String: String] {
    get {
        dict["a"] = "b"
    }
}
```

which indicates a read-only property.

You need to add the `set`ter

```
var dict: [String: String] {
    get {
      return [:]
    }
    set {
      dict["a"] = "b"
    }
}
```

But be careful, you can easily run into a infinite loop when you call the setter by itself (which it does in this example).

Actually this kind of computed property is only useful if you are going to map another value.

Comment: `var dict: [String: String]` has a getter that returns `return dict["a"]!` which isn't of type `[String: String]`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I updated the answer, but as mentioned this syntax is not very meaningful anyway.